# Using a function inside of a select statement to make a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, view

I have a function that calculates GST.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Gst]
(
      @JewelleryID int,
      @GstRate float 
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @Gst float
            SET @Gst = (SELECT Jewellery.Price * @GstRate
                      FROM Jewellery
                      WHERE JewelleryID = @JewelleryID)

      RETURN @Gst 
END

Select dbo.fn_gst(JewelleryID,0.1) AS GST
from Jewellery
```

I am now attempting to create a view but first I am doing the select statement.

Here is my code so far.

```
SELECT Sales.SaleID, Sales.SaleDate, Customers.FirstName, 
        Customers.LastName, Categories.Category, 
        Jewellery.Description, Types.Type, Jewellery.Year, 
        Jewellery.Price,  dbo.fn_Gst(JewelleryID, 10) 

FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Categories ON Customers.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN JewellerySales ON Sales.SaleID = JewellerySales.SaleID
INNER JOIN Jewellery ON Jewellery.JewelleryID = JewellerySales.JewelleryID
INNER JOIN Types ON Jewellery.TypeID = Types.TypeID
```

Clearly the `dbo.fn_Gst(JewelleryID, 10)` is incorrect as it throws 'cannot find either column "dbo" or the user definer function or aggregate, or the name is ambiguous. The function is scalar so it just return a value.

However I am having trouble figuring out where it is meant to go.

End result I am after is another column that displays the GST and then another column that is the GST column + the price column.

Comment: I think this might be a case of SQL Server sending you on a bit of a wild goose chase with that error message, try instead making sure that `JewelleryID` is not ambiguous changing the function call to `dbo.fn_Gst(Jewellery.JewelleryID, 10) AS GST`, (the alias will also been needed for this to work in a view). For what it is worth though, scalar functions are performance killers, and for something as simple as `a * b` I would change the column in the view to simply `Jewellery.Price * 10 AS GST`.

Comment: You want explicitely use a function or you can do in other ways?

Comment: @GarethD not having Jewellery.JewelleryID was the issue. I cant click your thing as an answer though if you want it points, as it was only a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modify the three places:**

“Types” change to “[Types]”

“Year” change to “[Year]”

dbo.fn_Gst(Jewellery.JewelleryID, 10) AS Gst

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sales.SaleID, 
       Sales.SaleDate, 
       Customers.FirstName, 
       Customers.LastName, 
       Categories.Category, 
       Jewellery.Description, 
       Types.Type, 
       Jewellery.Year, 
       Jewellery.Price,  
       dbo.fn_Gst(Jewellery.JewelleryID, 0.1),
       dbo.fn_Gst(Jewellery.JewelleryID, 0.1) + Jewellery.Price AS TotalPrice

FROM Sales 
JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
JOIN Categories ON Customers.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
JOIN JewellerySales ON Sales.SaleID = JewellerySales.SaleID
JOIN Jewellery ON Jewellery.JewelleryID = JewellerySales.JewelleryID
JOIN Types ON Jewellery.TypeID = Types.TypeID
```